# HttpURLConnection - When post Json Data the server on the other side receive string with backslashes

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection

When I Post Json Data using HttpURLConnection, the server on the other side receive a String with backslashes.

The `setRequestProperty` are set as:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
```

This is my code

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonEnvio = gson.toJson(object);

URL url = new URL(urlSend);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod(method);

if (headers != null) 
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
        connection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);

if (object != null) 
{
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(jsonEnvio.getBytes().length));

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(jsonEnvio);
    wr.close();
}

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

This is the string at variable `jsonEnvio`

`{"codOrdemComplexa":"12346544","codFornecedor":"56","codEtapaProcesso":"622635","codTipoElemento":"6","codTipoProjeto":"1","hash":"780fbd8103abe35899d219e8856123a6","nomeArquivo":"OrdemDeServico_12346544_Wed Feb15 18:05:25 BRST 2017","dataColetaEvidencias":"Feb 15, 2017 6:05:25 PM"}`

This is the string that the Server on the other side receive

`{\"codOrdemComplexa\":\"12346544\",\"codFornecedor\":\"56\",\"codEtapaProcesso\":\"622635\",\"codTipoElemento\":\"6\",\"codTipoProjeto\":\"1\",\"hash\":\"780fbd8103abe35899d219e8856123a6\",\"nomeArquivo\":\"OrdemDeServico_12346544_Wed Feb15 18:05:25 BRST 2017\",\"dataColetaEvidencias\":\"Feb 15, 2017 6:05:25 PM\"}`

The server on the other side respond that this is not a valid Json.

I need help to figure out what I need to change to fix that.

Using JDK 1.8.0_121

Comment: This code does not produce this output. What does the server code look like?

Comment: I don't have the code from the server on the other side. So you are saiyng that must be an issue on the other side?

Comment: What part of 'this code does not produce this output' didn't you understand?